# How to debug a maximum call stack size error in Unity 3D WebGL?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm having this weird issue when exporting my Unity 3D application to webGL. On my computer it runs fine (on Unity, that is) but when I put it online it gives me the Maximum Call Stack Size error on Chrome (firefox runs fine)
I did some research and most articles say it's because of a possible infinite loop on the code, I checked my code and there are no infinite loops (it would hang on firefox). So now I'm not sure how can I debug this. Can someone help out?

Update: I tried disabling objects from the scene, and even with an almost empty scene with no C# code running, it will still return this bug.

Comment: have you tried using the chrome dev tools to inspect the call stack?

Comment: I could do that but unity code is compiled for webgl, so I can't really trace it back to my app

Comment: it could still have some useful information

Comment: are you using the latest version of Unity?

Comment: I am using it, yes

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @slaw. It did not work for me by refreshing, but when I opened it in an Incognito mode, the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. I was able to fix it by just refreshing the browser cache. Ctrl-Shift-R wasn't enough on Firefox. I had to go into network console enable "Disable Cache" there.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I recently encountered this with 2021.3.30f1, in both Firefox and Chrome (though the errors are reported using different terminology).

One solution was to turn off compression in the Project Settings -> WebGL, Publishing Settings:

- Compression Format: Disabled
- Names as hashes off
- Data Caching: off
- Decompression Fallback: off

Answer (score 0):

Using latest Unity 2018.1.0f2 Personal this was happening. File --> Build Settings --> WebGL --> Player Settings - select WebGL Build. Then on the inspector tab changed the Api Compatibility Level from 4.x to .Net Standard 2.0. 
All working now.

Error in Chrome

> Uncaught RangeError : Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

Error in Firefox

> Too much Recursion.

[image: Unity WebGL panel]